Is grappling an incapacitated or prone target easier?
Grappling and Shoving are no longer initiated with contested ability checks. Instead, they require a strength or dexterity saving throw. Intuitively, I might imagine that certain conditions would influence the success or failure of that saving throw--e.g. being Incapacitated or Prone would disadvantage someone trying to avoid a grapple. However, it appears that RAW, neither of these conditions affect the outcome of the saving throw. Is that correct, or is grappling an incapacitated or prone target easier, somehow?

Grappling no longer has special rules for incapacitated targets
First of all, I think it's worth noting that nothing in the description for the Incapacitated condition has any effect on grappling in either the 2014 rules or the 2024 rules. In the 2014 rules, this is how the condition was described:


An incapacitated creature can't take actions or reactions.


The 2024 condition has more effects:

While you have the Incapacitated condition, you experience the following effects.
Inactive. You can’t take any action, Bonus Action, or Reaction.
No Concentration. Your Concentration is broken.
Speechless. You can’t speak.
Surprised. If you’re Incapacitated when you roll Initiative, you have Disadvantage on the roll.

However, there's nothing in either description that affects either ability checks (except Initiative rolls) or saving throws, so none of the effects listed above affect grapples under either the 2014 rules (contested ability check) or the 2024 rules (saving throw). The only reason that grapples are affected by this condition in the 2014 rules is that the rules for grappling specifically say so (emphasis added):

[...] Using at least one free hand, you try to seize the target by making a grapple check instead of an attack roll: a Strength (Athletics) check contested by the target's Strength (Athletics) or Dexterity (Acrobatics) check (the target chooses the ability to use). You succeed automatically if the target is incapacitated. [...]

Looking in the 2024 rules for grappling (in the glossary under Unarmed Strike), there is nothing about the Incapacitated condition:

Grapple. The target must succeed on a Strength or Dexterity saving throw (it chooses which), or it has the Grappled condition. The DC for the saving throw and any escape attempts equals 8 plus your Strength modifier and Proficiency Bonus. This grapple is possible only if the target is no more than one size larger than you and if you have a hand free to grab it.

Since the neither the Incapacitated condition's description nor the description of grappling say anything about an interaction between the two, then RAW the Incapacitated condition by itself does not make a creature any easier to grapple.
Likewise, Prone and grappling also have no interaction
Just like the description for grappling does not mention the Incapacitated condition, it also doesn't mention the Prone condition, and rules for the Prone condition have no effect on saving throws, so being Prone also does not make a creature easier to grapple.
